# Why will SQLite will not let me insert data to database

Tags: android, sqlite

Basically when i run the app, it says, it cannot add, num1input and num2input to the database because there is an error for

```
entry.createEntry(number_one, number_two, answer);
```

This is my code for MainActivity: i also took out the answer, because it comes up with an error, i think it's because the button that makes the calculation is not giving out the same output, and it's basically renaming a TextView from the XML.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button sqlUpdate, sqlView;
EditText sqlNumber1, sqlNumber2, sqlAnswer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLUpdate);
    sqlNumber1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1input);
    sqlNumber2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2input);
    sqlAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ans1);

    sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLopenView);
    sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    switch (arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.bSQLUpdate:
        boolean didItWork = true;
        try{
        String number_one = sqlNumber1.getText().toString();
        String number_two = sqlNumber2.getText().toString();
        String answer = sqlAnswer.getText().toString();

        DBA entry = new DBA(MainActivity.this);

        entry.open();

        entry.createEntry(number_one, number_two);

        entry.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            didItWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Damn!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }finally{
            if (didItWork){
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("It Worked");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success!");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
        break;
    case R.id.bSQLopenView:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.cmpcione.calculator.SQLVIEW");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}

public void sum(View v) {
    EditText number1input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1input);
    EditText number2input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2input);

    Integer num1=Integer.parseInt(number1input.getText().toString()),num2=Integer.parseInt(number2input.getText().toString());

    Integer ans1=num1+num2;

    TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans1);

    answer.setText(ans1.toString());

}
```

The code for the class DBA:

```
public class DBA {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NUMBER1 = "num1input";
public static final String KEY_NUMBER2 = "num2input";
public static final String KEY_ANSWER = "ans1";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CalculationsDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Calculation_table";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //creates table and rows
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +

                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
                KEY_NUMBER1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_NUMBER2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT NOT NULL);" 
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DBA(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public DBA open() {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();

}

public long createEntry(String number_one, String number_two) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NUMBER1, number_one);
    cv.put(KEY_NUMBER2, number_two);
    cv.put(KEY_ANSWER, answer);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NUMBER1, KEY_NUMBER2};
    //using the cursor to read from database
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = " ";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iNumber1 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER1);
    int iNumber2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER2);
    int iAnswer = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        //it gets the string of our index then it gets the first number and then the last
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iNumber1) + " " + c.getString(iNumber2) + "\n";
    }
    return null;


}
```

}
The full list of logcat: it's starting with not being able to insert the numbers to the database:

```
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cmpcione.calculator/com.cmpcione.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.cmpcione.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-11 17:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: You table is `Calculations`. But the stacktrace says `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Calculation_Table:`

Comment: Have you read the error message? SQLiteException: no such table: Calculation_Table

Comment: I see the problem you're having though, you're using the variable so it should be inserting into the table created.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the create entry not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016642/why-does-the-create-entry-not-working)

Comment: it was me i just reposted the question sorry, i will delete the other version

Answer (score 6):

Is it because your table is named `Calculations` and not `Calculation_Table`?

If you edited your table definition make sure you increment your database version so it goes into the `onUpgrade` method and recreates your database.

The next problem you're seeing `constraint failed` is caused by no value being inserted for the `answer` column.  the definition says it is `not null`.

Here's what you need to do:

```
public long createEntry(String number_one, String number_two) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NUMBER1, number_one);
    cv.put(KEY_NUMBER2, number_two);

    // the answer needs to be added to cv, uncomment the line and figure out the answer.
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(number_one) + Integer.parseInt(number_two);
    cv.put(KEY_ANSWER, answer);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: It's not that because i forgot to edit it, the table has been renamed

Comment: The error says that's the problem.  Make sure we're seeing the most current error and the most current code.

Comment: I checked the code and the logcat like 3 times, and it's the same

Comment: @user3383541 i just updated the answer, make sure you increment your version number.

Comment: i did that every time i tried it again, i increment the database version to 1 and still nothing :O :( ARGHHH!

Comment: that might be part of the problem, i think you need to start at 1, then 2,3,4,.... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, int) says starts at 1

Comment: i restarted eclipse, started with one and it's still the same, i edited the logcat too above ^^

Comment: added to the answer, at least now it's recognizing the table.  just need an answer.

Comment: i looked through the logcat and it's saying there is an error on line 79, which is the return statement from the method  return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

Comment: yes, you're inserting into the table but not setting the value for the answer column.  That has to be set, the definition says `not null` and there's no default value.  you must set that in your ContentValues.

Comment: how do i do that? could you edit the code above please? i kind of understand what you are saying but not fully

Comment: just uncommenting the `cv.put(KEY_ANSWER, answer);` line and adding the answer should fix it.

Comment: that comes to my next quesion, sorry to bother you, i understand what you are saying now, and i get it, but the answer, if you look at the code in the class MainActivity, the button which will update the answer will not work, because it will edit the text view in the xml

Comment: What do you want to happen? Are you wanting to check what the user input and insert the user's answer into the database?

Comment: because i uncommented and added the asnwer in the MainActivity class, and i also added to the create entry value :)

Comment: i want the user to add in 2 numbers, and the sum will be answer, and i want to add that to the database too, do you understand what i mean?

Comment: shouldnt you be calling the `sum` method in the `onClick` method somewhere? I dont see what the problem is.

Comment: i didnt put it in the method, because i set it up in the xml, that another button will make the calculation, and the code for that button, is set on click in the XML (which is listed atthe bottom of MainActivity) this will come up with error Damn, and no errors, in the log cat :(

Comment: the method works because the answer gets updated on the interface

Comment: there's no error in the logcat because you're in a try/catch.  you need to log the error yourself like `Log.d('error', errorMessage);`  Now the question is getting very specific to your code, you should probably ask another question on SO or go into the android chatroom for help.  This is too many comments on one answer.